# Python: Using multiprocessing module as possible solution to increase the speed of my function

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, optimization, multiprocessing

I wrote a function in Python 2.7 (on Window OS 64bit) in order to calculate the mean value of of the intersection area from a reference polygon (Ref) and one or more segmented (Seg) polygon(s) in ESRI [shapefile format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile). The code is quite slow because i have more that 2000 reference polygon (s) and for each Ref_polygon the function run for every time for all Seg polygons(s) (more than 7000). I am sorry but the function is a prototype.

I wish to know if [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) can help me to increase the speed of my loop or there are more performance solutions. if multiprocessing can be a possible solution i wish to know the best way to optimize my following function

```
import numpy as np
import ogr
import osr,gdal
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point
import osgeo.gdal
import osgeo.gdal as gdal

def AreaInter(reference,segmented,outFile):
     # open shapefile
     ref = osgeo.ogr.Open(reference)
     if ref is None:
          raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % reference)
     seg = osgeo.ogr.Open(segmented)
     if seg is None:
          raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % segmented)
     ref_layer = ref.GetLayer()
     seg_layer = seg.GetLayer()
     # create outfile
     if not os.path.split(outFile)[0]:
          file_path, file_name_ext = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(reference))
          outFile_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(outFile))[0]
          file_out = open(os.path.abspath("{0}\\{1}.txt".format(file_path, outFile_filename)), "w")
     else:
          file_path_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(outFile)
          file_out = open(os.path.abspath("{0}.txt".format(file_path_name)), "w")
     # For each reference objects-i
     for index in xrange(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount()):
          ref_feature = ref_layer.GetFeature(index)
          # get FID (=Feature ID)
          FID = str(ref_feature.GetFID())
          ref_geometry = ref_feature.GetGeometryRef()
          pts = ref_geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
          points = []
          for p in xrange(pts.GetPointCount()):
               points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
          # convert in a shapely polygon
          ref_polygon = Polygon(points)
          # get the area
          ref_Area = ref_polygon.area
          # create an empty list               
          Area_seg, Area_intersect = ([] for _ in range(2))
          # For each segmented objects-j
          for segment in xrange(seg_layer.GetFeatureCount()):
               seg_feature = seg_layer.GetFeature(segment)
               seg_geometry = seg_feature.GetGeometryRef()
               pts = seg_geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
               points = []
               for p in xrange(pts.GetPointCount()):
                    points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
               seg_polygon = Polygon(points)
               seg_Area.append = seg_polygon.area
               # intersection (overlap) of reference object with the segmented object
               intersect_polygon = ref_polygon.intersection(seg_polygon)
               # area of intersection (= 0, No intersection)
               intersect_Area.append = intersect_polygon.area
          # Avarage for all segmented objects (because 1 or more segmented polygons can  intersect with reference polygon)
          seg_Area_average = numpy.average(seg_Area)
          intersect_Area_average = numpy.average(intersect_Area)
          file_out.write(" ".join(["%s" %i for i in [FID, ref_Area,seg_Area_average,intersect_Area_average]])+ "\n")
     file_out.close()
```

Comment: My multiprocessing answer is below, but it's true that you should probably find a better algorithm since that will speed it up only linearly (5-10 times faster, depending on the power of your computer).

Comment: I personally find `concurrent.futures` easier to use in some situations than `multiprocessing` (`as_completed` is often simpler than `imap_unordered` and friends). While it wasn't added to the stdlib until 3.2, [`futures`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) is a complete backport to 2.x. I think in your use case, `multiprocessing` is easily simple enough, but it's worth knowing about for the future.

Comment: I had a blog post which goes through a similar case with an example of an embarrassingly parallel algortithm with Python  here: http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/a-really-simple-multiprocessing-python-example/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) package, and especially the `Pool` class. First create a function that does all the stuff you want to do within the for loop, and that takes as an argument only the index:

```
def process_reference_object(index):
      ref_feature = ref_layer.GetFeature(index)
      # all your code goes here
      return (" ".join(["%s" %i for i in [FID, ref_Area,seg_Area_average,intersect_Area_average]])+ "\n")
```

*Note* that this doesn't write to a file itself- that would be messy because you'd have multiple processes writing to the same file at the same time. Instead, it returns the string that needs to be written. Also note that there are objects in this function like `ref_layer` or `ref_geometry` that will need to reach it somehow- that's up to you how to do it (you could put `process_reference_object` as the method in a class initialized with them, or it could be as ugly as just defining them globally).

Then, you create a pool of process resources, and run all of your indices using `Pool.imap_unordered` (which will itself allocate each index to a different process as necessary):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool()  # run multiple processes
for l in p.imap_unordered(process_reference_object, range(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount())):
    file_out.write(l)
```

This will parallelize the independent processing of your reference objects across multiple processes, and write them to the file (in an arbitrary order, note).

Comment: Thanks David, I really appreciate. I am honest to say I din't get the part "# all your code goes here". Do i need to re-write a function as non-loop version (ex: just for only one Reference polygon)? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Gianni: that is, all the code in your for loop, from `# get FID (=Feature ID)` to `intersect_Area_average` (I didn't want to copy and paste it all).

Comment: Dear Robert i still missing how nested the "def process_reference_object(index)" after # For each reference objects-i
     for index in xrange(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount()):.......Sorry :P

Comment: @Gianni: Who is Robert? Anyway, the point is to take everything inside the `for index in xrange(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount()):` for loop and put it into a function. Then, `p.imap_unordered` runs that function for every index you want to run- the trick is that it splits up different indices into different pools.

Comment: @ David, in the end i need to write a nested function with your function inside  def AreaInter(reference,segmented,outFile):, because the unclear part (sorry it's a my missing you are great) is how read Ref and Seg in the multiprocessor loop

Comment: +1 to David who is known as Robert who is actually known as David for a clear answer and a lot of explanatory work… but why `Pool(5)`? Normally, if the default isn't good enough, you probably want `cpu_count()*2`, and really you want to profile with different possibilities. But 5 is a particularly odd number. I can understand not wanting to write a long discussion on what to actually use… but then why not just `Pool()`?

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry, 5 must have just been on the brain for some reason. I'll leave it as `Pool()`

Answer (score 2):

Threading can help to a degree, but first you should make sure you can't simplify the algorithm. If you're checking each of 2000 reference polygons against 7000 segmented polygons (perhaps I misunderstood), then you should start there. Stuff that runs at O(n<sup>2</sup>) is going to be slow, so maybe you can prune away things that will definitely not intersect or find some other way to speed things up. Otherwise, running multiple processes or threads will only improve things linearly when your data grows geometrically.