# Python: improving speed of my function with multiprocessing module. Some confusion

Tags: python, performance, optimization, multiprocessing

this a second post, part of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202285/python-using-multiprocessing-module-as-possible-solution-to-increase-the-speed).

I wrote a function in Python 2.7 (on Window OS 64bit) in order to calculate the mean value of of the intersection area from a reference polygon (Ref) and one or more segmented (Seg) polygon(s) in ESRI shapefile format. The code is quite slow because i have more that 2000 reference polygon (s) and for each Ref_polygon the function run for every time for all Seg polygons(s) (more than 7000). I am sorry but the function is a prototype.

following the suggestions of David Robinson

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool()  # run multiple processes
for l in p.imap_unordered(process_reference_object, range(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount())):
    file_out.write(l)
```

and [TimothyAWiseman](http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/a-really-simple-multiprocessing-python-example/), i wish to use in the optimize way multiprocessing in order to increase the speed of my function.

i have the following questions:

1. where is the best position to locate p = Pool().... Inside the
   second function (ex: segmentation_accuracy) or in the end?

i had try to insert here (in the end of segmentation_accuracy)

```
p = Pool()
for l in p.imap_unordered(object_accuracy, range(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount())):
    file_out.write(l)
file_out.close()
```

but my PC is freezing

2. can i improve (i think yes) my code and how?

---

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import math
import numpy as np
import osgeo.gdal
import ogr
import numpy
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def shapefile_NameFilter(inFile):
    if inFile.endswith(".shp"):
        return inFile
    else:
        raise ValueError('"%s" is not an ESRI shapefile' % inFile)

def object_accuracy(ref,seg, index,threshold=10.0,noData=-9999):
    """
    segmetation accuracy metrics
    """
    ref_layer = ref
    seg_layer = seg

    # convert in a shapely polygon
    ref_feature = ref_layer.GetFeature(index)
    # get FID (=Feature ID)
    FID = str(ref_feature.GetFID())
    ref_geometry = ref_feature.GetGeometryRef()
    #  exterior boundaries
    pts = ref_geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
    points = []
    for p in xrange(pts.GetPointCount()):
        points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
    # convert in a shapely polygon
    ref_polygon_exterior = Polygon(points)
    nHole = ref_geometry.GetGeometryCount()
    if nHole != 1:
    for h in range(1, nHole):
        #  interior boundaries or "holes" of the feature
        pts = ref_geometry.GetGeometryRef(h)
        points = []
        for p in range(pts.GetPointCount()):
            points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
        ref_polygon_interior = Polygon(points)
        ref_polygon_exterior = ref_polygon_exterior.difference(ref_polygon_interior)
    # Net Reference Polygon
    ref_polygon = ref_polygon_exterior
    # get the area
    ref_Area = ref_polygon.area
    # get centroid of the reference object-i
    geom, xy = ref_polygon.centroid.wkt.split(None, 1)
    xy = xy.strip('()').split()
    xcr, ycr = (float(i) for i in xy)
    # create empty lists
    nObject = 0
    Area_seg, Area_intersect = ([] for _ in range(2))
    RAor, RAos = ([] for _ in range(2))
    OverSeg, UnderSeg, OverMerg, UnderMerg = ([] for _ in range(4))
    qr, SimSize, SegError, Dsr = ([] for _ in range(4))
    # For each segmented objects-j
    for segment in xrange(seg_layer.GetFeatureCount()):
       seg_feature = seg_layer.GetFeature(segment)
       seg_geometry = seg_feature.GetGeometryRef()
       pts = seg_geometry.GetGeometryRef(0)
       points = []
       for p in xrange(pts.GetPointCount()):
           points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
       seg_polygon_exterior = Polygon(points)
       nHole = seg_geometry.GetGeometryCount()
       if nHole != 1:
       for h in range(1, nHole):
            #  interior boundaries or "holes" of the feature
            pts = seg_geometry.GetGeometryRef(h)
            points = []
            for p in range(pts.GetPointCount()):
                points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
            seg_polygon_interior = Polygon(points)
            seg_polygon_exterior = seg_polygon_exterior.difference(seg_polygon_interior)
       # Net Segemted Polygon
       seg_polygon = seg_polygon_exterior
       seg_Area = seg_polygon.area
       # get centroid of the segemented object-j
       geom, xy = seg_polygon.centroid.wkt.split(None, 1)
       xy = xy.strip('()').split()
       xcs, ycs = (float(i) for i in xy)
       # intersection (overlap) of reference object with the segmented object
       intersect_polygon = ref_polygon.intersection(seg_polygon)
       # area of intersection (= 0, No intersection)
       intersect_Area = intersect_polygon.area
       # Refinement in order to eliminate spurious effects
       if intersect_Area > (ref_Area*(float(threshold)/100)):
          # Union
          union_polygon = ref_polygon.union(seg_polygon)
          # area of union
          union_Area = union_polygon.area
          # Number of segmented objects
          nObject += 1
          # segmented object area
          Area_seg.append(seg_Area)
          # intersected (=overlapped) region area
          Area_intersect.append(intersect_Area)
          # Area-Based Measures
          # Relative Area of a reference object (RAor)
          RAor.append(intersect_Area/ref_Area)
          # Relative Area of a segmented object (RAos)
          RAos.append(intersect_Area/seg_Area)
          # OverSegmentation (OverSeg)
          OverSeg.append(1-(intersect_Area/ref_Area))
          # UnderSegmentation (UnderSeg)
          UnderSeg.append(1-(intersect_Area/seg_Area))
          # OverMerging (OverMerg)
          OverMerg.append((ref_Area - intersect_Area)/ref_Area)
          # UnderMerging (UnderMerg)
          UnderMerg.append((seg_Area -intersect_Area)/ref_Area)
          # Quality rate (qr)
          qr.append(1-(intersect_Area/(union_Area)))
          # SimSize
          SimSize.append(min(ref_Area,seg_Area)/max(ref_Area,seg_Area))
          # Mean Absolute Segmentation Error (SegError)
          SegError.append(abs(ref_Area - seg_Area)/(ref_Area + seg_Area))
          # Location-based Measures
          # Position discrepancy of segmented object to a reference object
          # Euclidean distance in the xy plane
          Eucdist_sr = math.sqrt(math.pow((xcs-xcr),2)+math.pow((ycs-ycr),2))
          Dsr.append(Eucdist_sr)
       # No segmented objects of intrest
       if nObject == 0:
            AREAs_average, SDs, seg_AreaMax = (noData for _ in range(3))
            AREAo_average, SDo, intersect_AreaMax = (noData for _ in range(3))
            ORrs,RAor_average,RAos_average = (noData for _ in range(3))
            OverSeg_average,UnderSeg_average  = (noData for _ in range(2))
            OverMerg_average,UnderMerg_average = (noData for _ in range(2))
            qr_average,SimSize_average,SegError_average, AFI = (noData for _ in range(4))
            Dsr_avarage,RPsr_average,dmax,D = (noData for _ in range(4))
       else:
            ORrs = (1.0/nObject)*100
            AREAs_average = numpy.average(Area_seg)
            SDs = numpy.std(Area_seg)
            seg_AreaMax = numpy.max(Area_seg)
            AREAo_average = numpy.average(Area_intersect)
            SDo = numpy.std(Area_intersect)
            intersect_AreaMax = numpy.max(Area_intersect)
            # Avarage for all segmented objects
            RAor_average = numpy.average(RAor)*100
            RAos_average = numpy.average(RAos)*100
            OverSeg_average = numpy.average(OverSeg)
            UnderSeg_average = numpy.average(UnderSeg)
            OverMerg_average = numpy.average(OverMerg)
            UnderMerg_average = numpy.average(UnderMerg)
            qr_average = numpy.average(qr)
            SimSize_average = numpy.average(SimSize)
            SegError_average = numpy.average(SegError)
            # Area Fit Index
            AFI = (ref_Area-seg_AreaMax)/ref_Area
            Dsr_avarage = numpy.average(Dsr)
            # Maximum Distance
            dmax = numpy.max(Dsr)
            # Avarage Realative Position (RPsr)
            RPsr_average = numpy.average(numpy.array(Dsr)/numpy.max(Dsr))
            # D index
            D = math.sqrt((math.pow(OverSeg_average,2)+math.pow(UnderSeg_average,2))/2)
       return(" ".join(["%s" %i for i in [FID, ref_Area, nObject, ORrs,\
            AREAs_average, SDs, seg_AreaMax, AREAo_average, SDo, intersect_AreaMax,\
            RAor_average, RAos_average, OverSeg_average, UnderSeg_average,\
            OverMerg_average, UnderMerg_average,qr_average, SimSize_average,\
            SegError_average, AFI, Dsr_avarage, RPsr_average, dmax, D]])+ "\n")


def segmentation_accuracy(reference,segmented,outFile,threshold=10.0,noData=-9999):
    """
    Segmentation accuracy

    """
    # check if reference and segmented are ESRI shapefile format
    reference = shapefile_NameFilter(reference)
    segmented = shapefile_NameFilter(segmented)
    # open shapefile
    ref = osgeo.ogr.Open(reference)
    if ref is None:
        raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % reference)
    seg = osgeo.ogr.Open(segmented)
    if seg is None:
        raise SystemExit('Unable to open %s' % segmented)
    ref_layer = ref.GetLayer()
    seg_layer = seg.GetLayer()
    # create outfile
    if not os.path.split(outFile)[0]:
        file_path, file_name_ext = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(reference))
        outFile_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(outFile))[0]
        file_out = open(os.path.abspath("{0}\\{1}.txt".format(file_path, outFile_filename)), "w")
    else:
        file_path_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(outFile)
        file_out = open(os.path.abspath("{0}.txt".format(file_path_name)), "w")
    # Header
    file_out.write(" ".join(["%s" %i for i in ["ReferenceFID","AREAr",\
    "nObject","ORrs","AREAs","SDs","AREAsMAX","AREAo","SDo","AREAoMAX",\
    "RAor","RAos","OverSeg","UnderSeg","OverMerg","UnderMerg","qr","SimSize",\
    "SegError","AFI","Dsr","RPro","dmax","D"]])+ "\n")
    for index in xrange(ref_layer.GetFeatureCount()):
        file_out.write(object_accuracy(index))
    file_out.close()
```

Comment: Have you considered checking to see if the bounding box of the polygons overlap before going on to do the full checks?

Comment: Dear George I will do in the future (with more calm and far dead-line). I need a moment to get the results now but i am planning to use a "bounding box of the polygons overlap" strategy. I don't know how now, but in the future yes i will.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look into something like Python-Profile (http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to identify the bottleneck in your code.  Once the limiting portion of code is known it is much easier to optimize, you might consider posting again with the bottleneck highlighted.  It is remarkably difficult for even the most experienced programmers to identify a bottleneck just from reading code such as the one you have posted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with shapely but it does look like you're unnecesarily re-building objects as part of the comparison loop. Creating all the objects you can for each shape in advance and storing them in a list might save quite a bit of time.